# Golang AST - add import "C"

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to add an `import "C"` to the AST at the begining. I want to add also some doc comment to the import node. want to look like this:

```
package main

/*
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {}
```

Doing this:

```
//parse the file
fset := token.NewFileSet()
f, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, dir, nil, parser.ParseComments)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
//get the package main
packageAst, ok := f["main"]
if !ok {
    fmt.Println("No package main in", dir)
    return
}
//add the import "C" with the comment
for _, file := range packageAst.Files {
    comment := &ast.CommentGroup{
        List: []*ast.Comment{
            &ast.Comment{
                Slash: file.Package,
                Text:  "/*\n#include \"postgres.h\"\n#include \"fmgr.h\"\n*/",
            },
        },
    }
    importC := &ast.GenDecl{
        TokPos: file.Package,
        Tok:    token.IMPORT,
        Specs:  []ast.Spec{&ast.ImportSpec{Doc: comment, Path: &ast.BasicLit{Kind: token.STRING, Value: "\"C\""}}},
    }
    file.Decls = append([]ast.Decl{importC}, file.Decls...)
    break
}
```

And the output is this:

```
package main

import "C"

func main() {}
```

The comment is not there. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's generally much easier to insert the text in the source directly, rather than manipulate the AST

Comment: After modifying the source directly, use [format.Source](https://godoc.org/go/format#Source) to gofmt the code.

Comment: But this is just one thing im doing with the source code. I'm also changing the input parameters of exported functions based by the types etc. so the I want the import "C" make with the ast package